# How to calculate trend line

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

I have the following dataset

```
5 338.45
6
7
8
9
10 350.75
11
12
13
14
15 380.70
```

I need to calculate the missing values by plotting a linear trend line between the values I know (5, 10 and 15)

I did that by doing (350.75-338.45)/6 = 2.05 then adding that between 5 and 10 so:

```
5 338.45
6 340.5
7 342.55
8 344.6
9 346.65
10 350.75
```

Then same between 10 and 15 by adding 4.99

```
10 350.75
11 355.74
12 360.73
13 365.72
14 370.71
15 380.70
```

My question is once all that is calculated, if I had new 5 and 15 values, how do I apply those same trendlines to it

I only have new 5 and 15, not the 10.

```
5 295.99  
6
7
8
9
10  
11
12
13
14
15 309.99
```

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

What you did seems fine.

If you have new values for 5 and 15 and **they replace the old ones**, you just need to repeat the process which you already did while using the new values.

But if you mean... **you need to add** the new values for 5 and 15 to the old dataset, then this would make no sense.

You are building a model here. You need to specify if you expect 5 (or 10) to have a single value or can have more than 1 values associated with it.

It really depends on what you're trying to model here and what your initial assumptions are.